# Calculating the eigenvalues of a representation with an unknown order

Tags: group-theory, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, characters

If I know that $\chi$ is a character of degree $2$ on $G$ and suppose $\chi(g) = 1$.
Prove that $\chi(g^2)= -1$.

Now, I know that $\rho(g)$ is a 2x2 matrix, so therefore there are 2 eigenvalues (which could be the same).

And $\chi(g) = Tr(\rho(g)) = \lambda_1 + \lambda_2 = 1$

I also know that $\lambda_1 $and $\lambda_2$ are the n-th roots of unity.

My question is, how do I use this information to prove that $\lambda_1^2 + \lambda_2^2 = -1$?

Comment: There is not enough info here for the conclusion, as it might just as well be the case that $\chi(g^2) = 1$.

Comment: The first line is the entire question - we aren't given any further information.

Comment: Actually, I was a bit hasty with my previous comment (for some reason I though we would have $\chi(1) = 1$ which is clearly not the case).

Comment: I'm guessing that I somehow have to show that the only way two n-th roots of unity can sum to 1 will result in the sum of their squares being equal to -1.  I just don't know how to do this!

Comment: So you have two roots of unity whose sum is real, so their complex parts are negative of each other. Also, their real parts must then be equal (as otherwise they would be of opposite sign which would make it impossible to get sum $1$). So they must be conjugate with real part $\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft - so I just tried it with $1/2 \pm ib$ and they sum to 1 but the sum of their squares don't definitely $= -1$

Comment: Which $b$ did you choose? There is only one for which the number is a root of unity.

Comment: Oh, I just left b as a variable. Which b should I use?

Comment: Ooh, is it the 6th root of unity???

Comment: Well, what roots of unity have real part $\frac{1}{2}$?

Comment: Thanks for your help, @TobiasKildetoft!!